# No enclosing instance of type is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type(e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of )

Tags: java, class, oop

```
public class oop {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        Manager boss = new Manager("Boss Man", 80000, 1987);
        boss.setBonus(5000);

        Employee[] staff = new Employee[3];
        staff[0] = boss;
        staff[1] = new Employee("Teller Tom", 50000, 1989);
        staff[2] = new Employee("Lender Lory", 40000, 1990);

        for (Employee empIndex : staff) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Name: %-11s\t\tEarnings: $%,.2f\t\tHired in: %s", empIndex.getName(), empIndex.getSalary(), empIndex.getHireYear()));
        }
    }
    class Employee {
        private String name;
        private double salary;
        private int yearHired;

          Employee(String nam, double sal, int yr) {
            System.out.println("Employee superclass");
            name = nam;
            salary = sal;
            yearHired = yr;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
        public double getSalary(){
            return salary;
        }
        public int getHireYear(){
            return yearHired;
        }
    }
    static class Manager extends Employee {
        private double bonus;

        public Manager(String name, double salary, int year){
            super(name, salary, year);
            System.out.println("Manager subclass");
            bonus = 0;
        }
        public double getSalary(){
            double baseSalary = super.getSalary();
            return baseSalary - bonus;
        }
        public void setBonus(double bon){
            bonus = bon;
        }
    }
}
```

Hey, I'm in first year of uni and I'm trying to help my professor with his demo which isn't working. I already fixed some errors but I still can't get it to work. This error occurs on 'public class oop'. Thank you in advance for the help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'd strongly  advise you to avoid using inner classes unless you *really* need to. You won't get this problem if you just use top-level classes.

Comment: You can add _static_ modifier to your _Employee_ class, similar to your _Manager_ class.  This will allow access to _Employee_ without the need of the enclosing class instance, this this case _oop_.  For reference, see _[Oracle - Nested Classes - Learning the Java Language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)_.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared Employee without static which means you must have an instance of the enclosing class `oop` to create Employee which you create using the reference such as `thatOop.new Employee(...)`

However it looks like you should just ensure that Employee can be created without an instance of oop, just make it a static class as you have already done with `Manager`:

```
static class Employee
```

Comment: thank you so much, I was sure I had tried that but it worked now, thank you!